# custom logging to database using http module

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I want to log all of Querystring or post data into database using Httpmodule.

I already tried capturing data like this:

```
HttpRequest req;
     string  pageparameterG = string.Empty,
        try
            {
               // get form:
               var formColl = req.QueryString;
               int i = 0, e = 0;
               foreach (string param in formColl.Keys)
                 {
                    try
                       {
                          string detailparam = formColl[param];
                          pageparameterG = string.Concat(pageparameterG, "&", param, "=", detailparam);
                          i++;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                           e++;
                           continue;
                        }
                        if (i == 0 && e == 0)
                           pageparameterG = "FAIL TO GET PARAMETER";
                    }
                }
       catch
            {
               pageparameterG = "FAIL TO GET PARAMETER";
             }
```

It did work on my MVC project using managed framework 4.0. But *it failed when I apply this on classic framework 2.0.*

Any suggestions?

Comment: what exactly failed? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: no error at all, if error, should return : "FAIL TO GET PARAMETER"